# Ubuntu 22.04.2 cannot install docker

Tags: server, docker

```
$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for david:
Ign:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Invalid response from proxy: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request  Server: nginx  Date: Tue, 13 Jun 2023 21:28:46 GMT  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8  Content-Length: 166  Connection: close     [IP: 60.191.80.11 443]
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server? I just ran the exact same command with Docker repo enabled with no errors whatsoever.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Yes, I am using https://mirrors.163.com/

Comment: The IP address 60.191.80.11 is owned by mirrors.163.com. So the problem lies here.

Comment: @ArturMeinild thanks, it fixed